# Using Multiprocessing in for Loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, queue, multiprocessing

I have some function with for loop like this for example.

```
def function(a,b,c):
    Vol = [100]
    b = Vol[0]
    for i in range(10000):
        b +=i
        Vol.append(b)
    return Vol[-1]
```

This is just an sample code. In my code, I need to calculate every 'for loop' to calculate the final result of the function.

Is there any method to decrease the time by using multiprocessing?

Comment: You should probably elaborate on what you expect your function to do. The example you give does not actually process its arguments. The question if multiprocessing is a good way to speed up your code really depends on what you try to accomplish.

Comment: @Fulco I want to speed up the iteration and get the final result of that operation, which is Vol[-1]

Comment: The question as posed is not specific enough to answer. First of all, you have not disclosed the amount of time your current implementation takes to run. Second, parallelizing your code puts requirements on how you structure your function input, and it brings some overhead. So all anyone can answer at this point is: it depends.